# Factoring a series of Matricies

Tags: matrices, factoring, matrix-equations

I have a graduate physics text which has an arbitrary matrix $M$. I am given the following 
$M^{0} + M^{1} + M^{2}...M^{n-1}$
and then it says this is equal to 
$(M^{n}-I)(M-I)^{-1}$, where $I$ is the identity matrix. I dont not see how this follows, IF anyone can show me I would appreciate it.

It looks like some sort of power series of Matrices, but I never could fill in the gap.

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(M-I)(I+M+\cdots+M^{n-1})$$
$$(I+M+\cdots+M^{n-1})(M-I)$$
$$=(M+M^2+\cdots+M^{n-1}+M^n)$$
$$-(I+M+\cdots+M^{n-2}+M^{n-1})$$
$$=M^n-I$$

> If $1$ is not the eigenvalue of $M$, that is to say $M-I$ is invertible, then
>   $$I+M+\cdots+M^{n-1}=(M-I)^{-1}(M^n-I)=(M^n-I)(M-I)^{-1}$$

This approach is similar to the geometric progression。

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you!